# MaaS automated provisioning of ESXi

Tags: vmware, maas

Is there a way in MaaS to automate the provisioning of an ESXi bare metal host.

Just like I want to be able to deploy Ubuntu/CentOS/Windows I would also like to be able to deploy ESXi and automatically to then add them to the ESXi cluster automatically.

Answer (score 4):

MAAS does not currently support deployment of ESXi onto bare metal; the simplest way to achieve that goal may be to use vSphere's [Auto Deploy](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features/auto-deploy) tooling, as described in this [blog post](http://keepingitclassless.net/2013/11/mass-esxi-deployment-using-auto-deploy-boot-from-san-and-powershell/).

Having said that, MAAS now includes built-in support for power control of /VMs/ running on top of an already-deployed vSphere/ESXi; see "[How to configure MAAS to be able to boot virtual machines via VMware type](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663771/how-to-configure-maas-to-be-able-to-boot-virtual-machines-via-vmware-type)" for details.

(We used to support ESXi via a virsh solution, as outlined in [this blog post](http://get-creativetitle.com/2014/10/18/setting-up-libvirt-on-an-ubuntu-machine-to-power-on-esxi-vms/), but that's been superseded by the native support.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but that adds yet another tool to the mix. I was hoping to have a single tool to do the job.

Comment: If it helps we are discussing this feature this very week as part of our roadmap planning sprint. If it gets approved we'll announce it.