# How to configure MAAS to be able to boot virtual machines via VMware type

Tags: maas, vmware-workstation

I've installed Ubuntu MaaS using VMware Workstation on a vm with Ubuntu 14.04 and upgraded it via ppa stable.

I'd like to add some vnodes to MaaS and setting them their Power Type as "VMware" but I don't know how I've to make that

[image]

I've also installed the package python-pyvmomi

> **sudo apt-get install python-pyvmomi --install-suggests**

as suggested here

http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.8/changelog.html

but nothing. anyone knows how making that? thanks in advance

SOLUTION:

as suggested me by Mike, the solution has been:

- create all my VMs under "Shared VMs";
- filled all parts in  "Add Hardware > Chassis" using as values my Host.

[image]

Then after few seconds I've seen all VMs in MaaS

[image]

run the commission step

[image]

Comment: I've tried to answer in general below. If that doesn't help, can you be more specific about where you're stuck? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for MAAS to be able to manage VMware Workstation VMs, they must exist under the `Shared VMs` folder in VMware Workstation.

Next, rather than adding nodes manually and then trying to set the power type, I would recommend using the `Add Hardware > Chassis` feature to add the nodes. This is a much more user friendly experience, as it will automatically discover all the nodes in a particular hypervisor, and configure them properly for use with MAAS, including the power type information.

Be very careful if you are using this with a production VMware system, since performing this operation will change the configuration of your virtual machines. If you are using a VMware setup which contains a mix of VMs which will be MAAS managed and VMs which will not be, I strongly recommend renaming the MAAS-managed VMs within the hypervisor so that their names start with something identifiable, such as "maas". Then you can use the `Prefix filter` option and specify (for example) "maas" to manage only those nodes.

When you enter your username and password, keep in mind that for VMware workstation, I've found that the username and password are the same as what you use for your OS login. (There are ways to add another user and give it access to your VMs if you aren't comfortable with giving MAAS that information.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. it's exactly that I want to make, the only problem now is  that I can't create VMs under the "Shared VMs". I've tried to run the connect but the answer is always the same "unable to connect to the workstation server. please ensure that it is running, and then retry by ..." I've also to run vmware via sudo but nothing....

Comment: I've tried to make that but if I select Chassic it's always necessary to fill the requests about "Host" "Username" ....

Comment: @RiccardoMagrini, first you need to use another tool to create the VMs you want to manage under "Shared VMs". (I use the GUI that comes with the product.) To connect to VMware Workstation remotely, you need to be able to access its SOAP interface, which is exposed over the HTTPS port. (you may need to use `ufw` or similar to open the port, if you are using a firewall.) If you aren't sure which port it's listening on, check `sudo netstat -anp | grep ^tcp.*LISTEN | grep vmware-hostd | awk '{ print $4 }'`. For me I see `:::443` and `0.0.0.0:443` in the output, which means it's on port 443.

Comment: @RiccardoMagrini, by the way, which version of VMware Workstation are you using? I have version 11.1.2, which looks a bit different than your screenshot.

Comment: @RiccardoMagrini Another question: Is MAAS running on the same system as VMware Workstation? If so, the host would be `127.0.0.1`, and you could use your own username and password for "Add Chassis". In any case, you *will* need to add VMs to "Shared VMs" for this to work. (For me, if I right-click "Shared VMs" on the left side of the VMware GUI, I can then choose `New Virtual Machine...`.)

Comment: now MaaS can see all VM created on VM Workstation...thanks a lots everyone...upgrade the question