# Does MaaS support deploying ESXi?

Tags: vmware, maas

I saw this post that is over a year old: [MaaS automated provisioning of ESXi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647958/maas-automated-provisioning-of-esxi)

Has there been any change?  Is ESXi a supported OS or on the roadmap to be supported?

Answer (score 1):

MAAS supports managing virtual machines in an ESXi, but the moment it does not allow deploying a machine with ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy ESXi via PXEboot with kickstart to customise the install. You will need:

- Syslinux 3.86 (4.x and newer will fail with ESXi)
- Kickstart script, include at least the commands below

  `accepteula`
  `install --firstdisk --overwritevmfs`
  `rootpw vmware123`
  `reboot`
- You can follow this with `%pre --interpreter=busybox` (to setup hostname and network config) and `%firstboot --interpreter=busybox` sections in the Kickstart file to customise the install.
- Kernel boot command as shown below, pointing to kickstart script (on http?)

`DEFAULT esxi6`
`PROMPT 0`
`MENU TITLE PXE Boot`
`LABEL esxi6`
 `MENU LABEL ^4) ESXi6`
 `KERNEL repos/ESXi-6.0.0/mboot.c32`
 `APPEND -c repos/ESXi-6.0.0/boot.cfg text gdbPort=none logPort=none ks=http://my-server.local/ks.cfg`
`LABEL hddboot`
 `LOCALBOOT 0x80`
 `MENU LABEL ^Boot from local disk`

- Copy of the installation ISO image with edited boot.cfg to ensure that all the paths are relative to the TFTP root. `` sed -e "s#/##g" -e "3s#^#prefix=repos/`basename $PWD`/\n#" -i.bak boot.cfg ``

Standard Linux tools are neater and easier to maintain than most vendor-provided solutions.

For PXElinux config see here: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50/GUID-5B132E25-0CFC-40D0-993D-40A83981E0E5.html

For install commands see here: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004582

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 2.5.0 MAAS can officially supports ESXi. Take a look at https://discourse.maas.io/t/maas-2-5-0-final-released/261